# C# scope and visibility

Tags: c#

I'm confused on a fact:

in the specification is said:

> The scope of a name is the region of program text within which it is
>   possible to refer to the entity declared by the name without
>   qualification of the name.

then

> The scope of a local variable declared in a
>   local-variable-declaration (§8.5.1) is the block in which the 
>   declaration occurs.

then

> Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to
>   refer to the local variable in a textual position that precedes the
>   local-variable-declarator of the local variable.

so at first it says that the scope of a local variable is the block and at the end it says that a local variable is usable only after its declaration (like in C/C++).

So is there any contradiction or I don't' understand well what the spec is saying?

Comment: The local variable is in scope, but you can't access it if it is declared afterwards. This compiler error should prevent you from careless mistakes. Why would you want to use a variable which isn't declared at this point? You can always move the declaration to the top of the method.

Comment: I see complimentary statements rather than contradictory ones.  The variable scope is defined as the block it's in, but only from the point onwards that it's declared.

Comment: The first quote has nothing to do with *local* variables, the second two do. The first quote is a general definition about what a scope is. The second describes how *local* variable scopes behave. The third simply notes that it's illegal to write: `a = 1; int a = 2;`

Comment: So the first point doesn't mean that it's always _valid_ to  "refer to an entity declared by the name without qualification of the name if it's in the same scope". it just tells you that it's _possible_. The compiler knows that you want to refer to a local variable in the same scope _after_ this, but it is _not allowed_ anyway. It's more about name resolution than accessibility.

Answer (score 4):

There is no contradiction.

A variable's scope is the region in which is defined, **and** it can only be used *after* it's declared.

Thus:

```
{
    int someVariable;
    ...
    someVariable = 0;
    ...
}
```

is valid. Whereas:

```
{
    int someVariable;
    ...
}
someVariable = 0;
```

isn't. And neither is:

```
{
    someVariable = 0;
    ...
    int someVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> The scope of a name is the region of program text within which it is possible to refer to the entity declared by the name without qualification of the name.

This rule states that given:

```
public static class TestClass
{
  public static int Value { get; set; }
  public static string ValueString
  {
    get { return TestClass.Value.ToString(); }
  }
}
```

We can omit the `TestClass` qualification of `Value` in `ValueString` because `Value` is in scope:

```
public static class TestClass
{
  public static int Value { get; set; }
  public static string ValueString
  {
    get { return TestClass.Value.ToString(); }
  }
}
```

However, if we also have:

```
public static void TestMethod()
{
  TestClass.Value = 3;
}
```

Then we cannot remove the `TestClass.` part, as there is no `Value` in scope.

> The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration (§8.5.1) is the block in which the declaration occurs.

Consider:

```
if (true)
{
  int x = 3;
}

x++; // CS0103 The name 'x' does not exist in the current context
```

We get the [CS0103](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f.aspx) compilation error because we are trying to use `x` somewhere where `x` does not exist.

> Within the scope of a local variable, it is a compile-time error to refer to the local variable in a textual position that precedes the local-variable-declarator of the local variable.

```
if (true)
{
  x++; // CS0841 Cannot use local variable 'x' before it is declared
  int x = 3;
}
```

Here we get a [CS0841](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397739%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) error instead. `x` exists in this scope, so the second rule you quote is being followed. It is being used though before it is declared, so the third rule you quote is not being followed. The different compilation error reflects the fact that a different rule has been broken.